# Can you use the default resource pack as a template?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to create a resource pack for an adventure map and I don't feel safe downloading a template. Is it possible that I can just copy the default Minecraft resource pack and paste it into the resourcepack folder and edit it to my liking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

1. Navigate to your `.minecraft` folder (`%appdata%/.minecraft/` on Windows usually)
2. Open `versions` folder
3. Open the folder for the version you would like to create a resource pack for
4. Open the `.jar` file with an archiving software such as WinRAR (right click, Open with WinRAR)
5. Navigate inside the `assets` folder and extract the `minecraft` folder
6. That folder is now your resource pack template! Rename the folder to whatever you would like to name your resource pack and copy it into the `Resource packs` folder. You can now edit it as you wish!

Hope I helped. If you need any more details or would like me to create a template for you to use (I guarantee it will be safe!) just comment.

Comment: I tried this but i don't have any applications that can open the .Jar file. If I download a template do i need Archiving software to edit it?

Comment: No you do not. However, I would recommend getting winRAR or 7zip, as they are very useful tools. You do not need archiving software after extraction either, so you can just get the winRAR 30 day trial and then un-install it.

Comment: Ok thanks I probably will get them after I make this adventure map, I want to finish the resource pack before 1.9 comes out.

Comment: How do you open it *without* the archiver? Say your administrator doesn't let you download such?

Comment: @CalebWoodman You can simply rename the file to a .zip (replace the .jar with .zip). You should then be able to open it without any additional software.

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work on my computer, but it works elsewhere :P

Answer (score -2):

I have gotten stuck in this before. But I have a fix.

Download a texture pack and keep the folders and delete all but one of their contents then run it in minecraft by placing it into  %appdata%/Roaming/.minecraft/recoursepacks on windows, Unfortunately I have not seen the place where to place it.

THEN play minecraft by going into the minecraft Java /options/resource packs.